# Como pegar o valor da variavel dentro de uma function em IONIC?

Tags: angular, ionic

```
  getListTodayOrders(): InterfaceOrders {
    const url = 'http://oneqbackend.herokuapp.com/api/listas';
    this.http.get(url).subscribe((data: InterfaceOrders) => {
        this.data_return = data;
        console.log(' Valor trabalha bem aqui ==> ' , this.data_return);
      });
      console.log(' Aqui o valor desaparece ==> ' , this.data_return);
      return this.data_return;
  }
```

inspect:

Valor trabalha bem aqui ==>  (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
Aqui o valor desaparece ==>  undefined

Comment: Onde declarou **data_return**?

Comment: O problema é que o subscribe é assíncrono, ou seja, quando você executa a função para receber o valor ele já passa para a linha debaixo, e quando ele termina de buscar a informação na url ele atribui o valor.

Comment: certo. resolvido. obrigado pessoal.